# Countable ordinals having a certain property

Tags: set-theory, ordinals

Which are the countable ordinals $\lambda$ such that, for every sequence of ordinals $\alpha_i\ (i\in\mathbb{N})$ such that

1. $\ $it is strictly increasing for all sufficiently large $i$
2. $\ $$\alpha_i<\lambda\ $ for all $i\in\mathbb{N}$
3. $\ $$\sup\{ \alpha_i:i\in\mathbb{N}\}=\lambda$,

there exists an ordinal $\beta<\lambda$ such that there exists a sequence $\gamma_i$,  with $\gamma_i+\beta=\alpha_i$ for all $i\in\mathbb{N}$, verifying 1.,2. and 3. above.

Furthermore, if such ordinals exist, how are they characterized? Thanks.

Comment: What is the meaning of "definitely in $i$?"

Comment: @marcofarotti Am I correct in assuming that "$\alpha_i-\beta\neq \alpha_i$ definitely in $i$" means that for all $i$, $\alpha_i-\beta\neq \alpha_i$?

Comment: I have just corrected

Comment: Given ordinals $\alpha_i$ and $\beta$, how do you define $\alpha_i-\beta$?

Comment: @JohnBentin Clarified.

Comment: Presumably you want to require $\beta\not=0$.

Comment: @NoahSchweber: One of the $\alpha_i$ may be an indecomposable ordinal...

Comment: @ChadK Yes, but my point was that if we're allowed to take $\beta=0$ then *every* ordinal trivially satisfies the desired property (since the new $\gamma$-sequence can just be the $\alpha$-sequence itself).

Comment: @NoahSchweber:  The original question had $\beta+\gamma_i=\alpha_i$ and made some sense.  The OP got a correct and comprehensive answer.  Now went and reversed it to something that makes no sense.

Comment: Why it makes no sense? (I agree that $\beta\ne 0 $ has to be specified). Btw, the answer considered a different definition of subtraction than it was present in the original question. In the current form there is no explicit subtraction anymore, and it makes sense to me.

Comment: I did not "consider a different definition of subtraction than it was present in the original question." There was no definition of subtraction present in the original question. So I chose the meaningful way to define it (the one where differences exist and are unique).

Comment: Well, in the version I saw there was one, probably it was edited since John Bentin above asked for clarifications.

Comment: The edit history is visible. The first post gives no definition of subtract. I recall, because I asked myself when writing my original solution whether I had the correct definition of subtraction, and I believed I must, since the other one is not necessarily uniquely defined. That's my fault for assuming.

@uagi Thank you for pointing out my misreading in the comment thread on my deleted answer.

Comment: @MarcoFarotti Are you sure that you want to ask that $\alpha_i=\gamma_i+\beta$ for all $i\in\mathbb{N}$? Even if we only ask for this for sufficiently large $i$, if $\lambda$ is not of the form $\nu+\omega$, then we can select $\alpha_i\uparrow \lambda$ where each $\alpha_{2i-1}$ is a limit ordinal and $\alpha_{2i}$ is a successor. Then do not exist $\beta\neq 0$ and $\gamma_i$ such that $\gamma_i+\beta=\alpha_i$ for all $i$, because $\alpha_i$ is a limit/successor when $\beta$ is. 

Would you be satisfied with $\alpha_i=\gamma_i+\beta$ on a subsequence?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let us say that an ordinal $\xi$ is **very good** if for any $(\alpha_i)_{i=1}^\infty \subset \xi=[0,\xi)$ such that there exists $i_0\in \mathbb{N}$ such that $(\alpha_i)_{i=i_0}^\infty$ is strictly increasing to $\xi$, there exist $j_0\geqslant i_0$, $\beta\in\xi$, and $(\gamma_i)_{i=j_0}^\infty\subset \xi$ such that $(\gamma_i)_{i=j_0}^\infty$ strictly increases to $\xi$ and $\alpha_i=\gamma_i+\beta$ for all $i\geqslant j_0$.

Recall that a subset $I\subset \xi$ is called *cofinal in* $\xi$ if $\sup I=\sup\xi$. The *cofinality* of $\xi$ is the minimum cardinality of a cofinal subset. An ordinal has cofinality $0$ iff it is $0$, it has cofinality $1$ iff it is a successor.  In order for there to exist a sequence $(\alpha_i)_{i=1}^\infty$ which is strictly increasing to $\xi$, the cofinality of $\xi$ must be exactly $\aleph_0$. So if $\xi$ is any ordinal with cofinality not equal to $\aleph_0$, it will vacuously be very good, because there will be no $\alpha_i$ as in the hypothesis of the definition of very good to violate the required property. So, for the remainder of the problem, I will amend the definition of **very good** to require that the ordinal $\xi$ also have cofinality $\aleph_0$ (the non-vacuous case).

> **Claim:** An ordinal $\xi$ is very good if and only if there exists $\nu$ such that $\xi=\nu+\omega$.

**Proof:** Assume $\xi=\nu+\omega$ and $\alpha_i\uparrow \xi$. Without loss of generality, we can assume $\alpha_i>\nu$ for all $i$, so $\alpha_i=\nu+m_i$ for some $m_i\uparrow \omega$. Let $\beta=1$ and $\gamma_i=\nu+(m_i-1)$. So $\alpha_i=\gamma_i+1=\gamma_i+\beta$ and $\gamma_i\uparrow \xi$. So $\nu+\omega$ is very good.

Assume $\xi$ has cofinality $\aleph_0$ and $$\xi\notin\{\nu+\omega:\nu\in \textbf{Ord}\}.$$  Fix $\mu_i\uparrow \xi$, which exists because of the cofinality of $\xi$. Let $\eta$ be the smallest exponent which appears in the Cantor normal form of $\xi$ and note that for some $\zeta$, $$\xi=\zeta+\omega^\eta.$$   Since we have assumed that $\xi\notin \{\nu+\omega:\nu\in \textbf{Ord}\}$, it must be the case that $\eta>1$. Since $\mu_i\uparrow \xi$, we can assume without loss of generality that $\mu_i>\zeta$ for all $i$, so we can write $\mu_i=\zeta+\rho_i$ for $\rho_i\uparrow \omega^\eta$.  Since $\eta>1$, it follows that $\omega+1<\omega^\eta$. Since $\rho_i<\omega^\eta$, it follows that $\rho_i+\omega+1<\omega^\eta$ for all $i$. Since $\sup_i \rho_i=\omega^\eta$, it follows that for any $i$, there exists $j>i$ such that $\rho_j>\rho_i+\omega+1$. Recursively select $j_1<j_2<\ldots$ such that $j_1=1$ and $\rho_{j_i}+\omega+1<\rho_{j_{i+1}}$.  By relabeling, we can assume without loss of generality that $j_i=i$, so that $\rho_i+\omega+1<\rho_{i+1}$ for all $i$. Define $$\alpha_{2i-1}=\zeta+\rho_i+\omega$$ and $$\alpha_{2i}=\zeta+\rho_i+\omega+1$$ for all $i$. By construction, $\alpha_i$ is strictly increasing. Since $\rho_i+\omega+1<\rho_{i+1}<\omega^\eta$, $$\alpha_{2i-1}<\alpha_{2i}=\zeta+\rho_i+\omega+1<\zeta+\omega^\eta=\xi.$$  So each $\alpha_i<\xi$. Since $\alpha_{2i-1},\alpha_{2i}>\zeta+\rho_i$ and $\zeta+\rho_i\uparrow \xi$, $\alpha_i\uparrow\xi$.

Suppose that there exists $\beta\neq 0$ such that for all sufficiently large $i$, there exists $\gamma_i$ such that $\alpha_i=\gamma_i+\beta$. Then if $2i-1$ is sufficiently large, $$\zeta+\rho_i+\omega=\alpha_{2i-1}=\gamma_{2i-1}+\beta,$$ which implies that $\beta$ must be a limit ordinal, since $\omega$ is. But then $$\zeta+\rho_i+\omega+1=\alpha_{2i}=\gamma_{2i}+\beta,$$ which implies that $\beta$ must be a successor, since $1$ is. This is a contradiction, an shows that $\xi$ cannot be very good.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I would just like clarification on the point where you show that $\alpha_i\uparrow \xi$ using the fact that $\alpha_i>\zeta+\rho_i$. It seems to me that for $i=2$ it is found that $\alpha_2=\zeta+\rho_1+\omega+1<\zeta+\rho_2$.

Comment: Yes, you are right. It should not have been $\alpha_i$ and $\rho_i$. It should have been $\alpha_{2i-1}$ and $\alpha_{2i}$ which are greater than $\zeta+\rho_i$. I have corrected it. Thanks.